# how can i rearrange the letters in the name with this code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, append, concatenation

there are 3 errors in the code, can you guys please help me find them, I am just a beginner. I need to **append (concatenate)** the letter **from Var1 to namelist** variable, which is a list variable. But there seems to be a problem as i is a string.

```
namelist = []

var1 = input( "Enter the name you want to validate ").upper()

namelist.append(var1[0])

for i in var1[1:]:
  for j in (namelist):
     if(j>=i):
       namelist.insert(i,namelist.index(j))
       break
     else:
       i.append(namelist)

print(namelist)
```

expected result: to run the code swiftly to rearrange letters in the name

Comment: fix indentation first

Comment: And write what you really want to do. What is the expected result of code?

Comment: what is the value of var12?

Comment: Do you even run this code?

Comment: thank you for your time guys, but it was written by someone else and asked to find three mistakes in the code. i just started training on python. I would be great if you can help me with 3 mistakes that's it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please use clear names for variables.
What exactly do you want to reach with your code?

You can use this code to get an list of the letters:

```
NameList = []
Input = input("Enter the name you want to validate:\n").upper()
for Character in Input:
    NameList.append(Character)
print(NameList)
```

And set a variable to the reverse with:

```
NameList = []
Input = input("Enter the name you want to validate:\n").upper()
for Character in Input:
    NameList.append(Character)
Output = "".join(NameList[::-1])
```

Comment: completely agree with you bro,but this code is not written by me, our great tutor asked us to find three mistakes in the code ahead of our syllabus. your help is appreciated

Comment: thank you for your time guys, but it was written by someone else and asked to find three mistakes in the code. i just started training on python. I would be great if you can help me with 3 mistakes that's it

Answer (score 0):

its seems like you vwant to reverse string

there are several ways, here are some with basic for loop

```
namelist = []
var1 = input( "Enter the name you want to validate ").upper()
for i in range(1, len(var1) + 1):
    namelist.append(var1[len(var1) - i])
print (namelist)
print ("".join(namelist))
```

output:

```
Enter the name you want to validate Hello
['O', 'L', 'L', 'E', 'H']
OLLEH
```

.

```
namelist = ''
var1 = input( "Enter the name you want to validate ").upper()
for i in range(1, len(var1) + 1):
    namelist = namelist + var1[len(var1) - i]
print (namelist)
```

output:

```
Enter the name you want to validate hello
OLLEH
```

.

```
def reverse(text):
    rev_text = ""
    for char in text:
        rev_text = char + rev_text
    return rev_text

print (reverse("hello"))
```

output:

```
olleh
```